# Assigning macro to Excel ActiveX ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, activex

So I have a VBA to script that creates a Form Control Combobox on the active sheet and runs a macro using `.OnAction = "myModule"` whenever the user selects anything within the combobox. Now I'm trying to mess around with the ActiveX Combobox and but can't seem to find an equivalent way of assigning the `"myModule"` macro to the ActiveX Combobox through VBA like I did to the Form Control Combobox. Is this something that's possible? Any and all help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Just add the event handler to the sheet's code module:  `Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()` or whatever event you want to handle (assuming it's named `ComboBox1`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried this but it didn't seem to work. However when I opened View Code in Design Mode and copy/pasted my code into the Private Sub for the Combobox everything worked and both Subs were named the same. I'll check out this other thread see if it can shed some light on my problem.